# How to fully replicate ADX + DI Indicators in Excel?

Tags: backtesting, indicator, excel, moving-average

For black box testing, I was hoping that I could replicate the ADX + DI+ and DI- indicators that are provided in trading platforms such as ThinkOrSwim, ScottradeElite etc.

However, I noticed that even after applying the formula I found on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_directional_movement_index), I noticed that initially calculated data tends to be off by a large margin when compared to ThinkOrSwim or ScottradeElite.

Example spreadsheet is based on HIMX @ [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBv1C-XxmhdxwqztsqyFVxSeNxWNkor_DDZ3JcjjJYo/edit?usp=sharing).
In the spreadsheet, you will see the ADX + DI oscillators that I calculated. Here is the screenshot of my calculated ADX + DI
[image: HIMX in self calculated spreadsheet]

Below is the screenshot based on ScottradeElite and ThinkOrSwim for HIMX
[image: HIMX in ScottradeElite]
[image: HIMX in ThinkOrSwim]

The period for the ADX & DI are 14 periods.

I have been spending countless hours, trying to figure out why my calculated results would deviate from the existing trading platforms. However, I have not been able to spot mistake. Can anyone help me out by pointing out what I am missing? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is attempting to implement technical analysis indicators, which is not pertinent to quant finance.

Answer (score 1):

I think wiki calculated upon new way and your excel calculated upon Wilder way (Wilder book).

I have same issue when use both method. Look like new Metastock 5 software offer both method.

Comment: Which part is the new way? Because I did state that I applied what I found from the Wiki?